# How to render empty image fields created with SQLAlchemy-imageattach without "OSError: there is no original image yet" exception

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

I am trying to use [sqlalchemy-imageattach](https://sqlalchemy-imageattach.readthedocs.io/) to attach images to a db.Model, and render them in a template with flask/jinja2.
This all works fine as long as there actually is an image attached. If the field is empty an exception (OSError: there is no original image yet) is thrown. How can either avoid the exception on empty fields or add some exception handling to the jinja2 template? Thanks!

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy_imageattach.stores.fs import HttpExposedFileSystemStore
from sqlalchemy_imageattach.context import (pop_store_context,
                                            push_store_context)
from sqlalchemy_imageattach.entity import Image, image_attachment


app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///:memory:'

store = HttpExposedFileSystemStore(
    path='images',
    prefix='static/images/'
)
app.wsgi_app = store.wsgi_middleware(app.wsgi_app)


class Person(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'person'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    image = image_attachment('PersonImage')

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


class PersonImage(Image, db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'person_image'

    person_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey('person.id'),
        primary_key=True)
    person = db.relationship('Person')


@app.before_request
def start_implicit_store_context():
    push_store_context(store)


@app.teardown_request
def stop_implicit_store_context(exception=None):
    pop_store_context()


@app.route('/')
def index():
    person = Person(name='Hello')
    # with open('test.jpg', 'rb') as f:
    #     person.image.from_file(f)
    db.session.add(person)
    db.session.commit()
    return render_template('index.html', person=person)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{ person.name }}
    {{ person.image }} <!-- THIS FAILS ON EMPTY FIELDS -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, to answer my own question:
You have to use `{{ person.image.original }}` in the template or check for `if person.image.count()`.
The sqlalchemy-imageattach [documentation](http://sqlalchemy-imageattach.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.0/guide/context.html#getting-image-urls) just mentions that `{{ person.image }}` expands to `<img src="{{ user.picture.locate() }}" width="{{ user.picture.width }}" height="{{ user.picture.height }}">`.
This does not work for empty image fields, and also does not work when using the obvious solution to check `{% if person.image %}`, because sqlalchemy-imageattach does not return `None` on empty image field but always throws an exception.
The releveant code is [here](https://github.com/dahlia/sqlalchemy-imageattach/blob/master/sqlalchemy_imageattach/entity.py#L864):

```
image = self.original
if not image:
    raise IOError('there is no original image yet')
return image
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code in index.html as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{ person.name }}
    {% if person.image is not none %}
       {{ person.image }} 
    {% else %}
       <img src="default.png">
    {% endif %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This also throws the exception. The solution is to use `person.image.original` or check for `person.image.count()`. I think this is not very clear in the [documentation](http://sqlalchemy-imageattach.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.0/guide/context.html#getting-image-urls).

Answer (score 0):

Simple use a if condition.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{ person.name }}
    {{ person.image if person.image}}
  </body>
</html>
```